# What does it mean "GML is an XML grammar"?

Tags: gml, xml, ogc

I'm trying to get my head around the theoretical side of XML and GML. The OGC web page for GML states that:

> The Geography Markup Language (GML) is an XML grammar for expressing
>   geographical features.

But what does it mean by a "*grammar*"? I can't see that phrase (as a noun) used anywhere else. Is it a unique GML meaning?

I see the terms "language", "schema", "format" and "standard". Are they the same thing?

So can I say that GML is an XML schema? Or would that mean something different? If so, is there a single XSD file that defines the entire GML specification?

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. All very useful information. Things are slowly becoming clearer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When someone designs a class of XML documents for representing information in a particular domain, they will sometimes call this an XML grammar, or a vocabulary, or a schema, or a document type, or even a language. The terminology isn't consistent. There's perhaps a different emphasis: calling it a schema implies that an XML Schema is the primary way in which the grammar/vocabulary is specified; but they all mean essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

From W3C's [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) recommendation:

> [Definition: The XML **document type declaration** contains or points to [markup declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-markupdecl) that provide a grammar for a class of documents. This grammar is known as a document type definition, or **DTD**. The document type declaration can point to an external subset (a special kind of [external entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-extent)) containing markup declarations, or can contain the markup declarations directly in an internal subset, or can do both. The DTD for a document consists of both subsets taken together.]

As for GML, you are correct that it has evolved from using [DTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition)s to [XML Schema Definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29). You can download these files here: http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/

See also the [GML Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language) for an overview of the [history of GML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language#History).

The W3C's [XML Schema Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) is another good resource for learning about XSDs, but curiously no mention of the word 'grammar'.

Answer (score 6):

Every XML document essentially has some given structure. When the structure is formally specified, we usually talk about a given *XML grammar*.

The formal specification can take many forms, e. g. [DTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) (Document Type Definition) or [XML Schema Definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) (XSD). XSD itself is a XML document and is now being used for GML. There are also other means of specifying XML structure, like [RELAX NG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG). These can all be effectively used for validating that a XML document conforms to the schema (grammar) as specified.

Even if you unambiguously describe a XML document structure in pure English, it does have a grammar.

So, to answer your question, we could say that GML is a XML grammar for which a XML Schema Specification exists ([link](http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/)).

Another term used in place of *XML grammar* is also *XML dialect*.