# What is a GML file?

Tags: gml

I am writing some training notes for new QGIS users at my work.

I have a section on types of vector files; ESRI Shapefile, MapInfo Tab and GML & GZ so far.

We sometimes use the UK Land Registry INSPIRE polygons, supplied as .gml, and Ordnance Survey MasterMap supplied as .gz

So I have written a paragraph on shapefiles and Tab files, but have struggled to come up with anything succinct for GML files. I have tried to understand the Wikipedia entry [Geographic Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language) so I understand that it is markup language for geographic information, as the name obviously implies.

But then the details require a degree of technical understanding that I am finding pretty impenetrable.

I have had a look at other web pages as well and they all more or less say the same thing, even the GIS Stackechange tag for gml that says *"Geography Markup Language (GML) is an OGC Standard for expressing geographical features"* - doesn't, to my mind, shed any light.

Also the question [What does it mean "GML is an XML grammar"?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22607/what-does-it-mean-gml-is-an-xml-grammar) goes over my head.

I am looking for a short paragraph that explains what it is for a new user (and myself clearly)

The best I can come up with at the moment is...

> GML is a vector file format that allows for geographic data to be kept
>   as a text file that can be shared easily between systems

It's easy enough to open a GML file in QGIS, and work with it, so perhaps this explanation more or less be skipped over anyway, but then how does a GML get created, in what software? I'd be looking for this to be included as part of the answer.

Or am I overcomplicating it?

Comment: The Geography Markup Language (GML) is an XML grammar for expressing geographical features > more details https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml

Comment: Look into the new OS ZoomStack Products (released end of January 2019) they come as geopackage (making it much easier to load and go in QGIS) no converting. > https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html#ZMSTCK

Comment: Zoomstack does not contain master map that is still shipped as gml.

Comment: Open MasterMap (Coming soon in 2019). get ready for Geopackage > https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/about/news/2018/mastermap-announcement.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the OS Open and the Geopackage, now downloaded and already in use. It's great. I am still not sure what a gml file is though! I do have GeoPackage to add to my training notes as well now.

Comment: Would it be true to say that a gml in the context of my question is a 'read-only' file?

Comment: I am also thinking that I could add "...like any markup language it can  translated by software that understands the language into something that can be understood by a human" ? Or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

Herewith an answer to my own question based on the information I have gleaned, and with some new understanding. If it needs tweaking I am hoping it may be commented upon over time.

> Markup language, as the name implies is a way of "Marking up" text. A software application can then interpret this and display the marked up text in a specific way.

From [Wikipedia - Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language#Scribe,_GML_and_SGML) "*In computer text processing, a markup language is a system for annotating a document in a way that is syntactically distinguishable from the text.*

"*HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) is a markup language that web browsers use to interpret and compose text, images, and other material into visual or audible web pages*." From [Wikipedia - HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)

For example:

```
<B>If this was HTML this text will be displayed in a web browser in bold because it
has been marked by tags indicated by the <> brackets and the instruction B for Bold<\B>
```

> GML is a type of markup language, based upon another called XML. It is a language that allows for geographic data to encoded as text. A text file can be shared easily between systems.

Below is a copy and paste of a very small part of a GML file opened in Notepad. The co-ordinates of a geometry are stored as a string of text that is *markedup* with information that the reading software can interpret and display as, in this case, polygons.

```
<AB:GEOMETRY><gml:Polygon srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="9">
<gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList>611745.88 141314.13 656755.48 141362.72 
611459.48 148360.82 611779.27 141349.98 611798.72 141339.10 617802.75 141247.74 
611506.79 14</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></AB:GEOMETRY>
```

Comment: XML is strictly speaking a meta language, it defines a way of defining mark up languages such as GML, through the use of 'Schema'. XML is itself a subset of SGML (Standard Generalized Markup Language).

Comment: A GML file is a well-formed XML file that is valid against a/the GML application schema